# Computation of average number of hops for an atom to reach a certain distance

Tags: conditional-probability, monte-carlo, computational-statistics, distributions

I apologize if this has been asked before. I tried searching all previous posts to look at different forms of this problem (such as random 2d walks on a lattice, relation to Isling's work, etc.). I posted this question to statistical physics section but I hope this is more relevant for this thread.

The problem is as follows (same as a random walk from the origin on a 2D lattice): there is an atom at the 2D Cartesian origin (0,0) and hops a unit distance with equal probability in one of the four directions. Understandably, the 2D joint distribution of the final coordinates $(x,y)$ after $N$ steps can be modeled through either a multinomial, or matrix convolution approach. I am trying to estimate the average number of hops it takes to reach a certain distance $d$.

I was able to decipher from numerous sources (including the original Whipple,McCrea paper that discussed the 2d random walk problem in detail) that the expected average number of hops is $ \approx d^2 $.

In order to show this, I attempted to compute the discrete probability mass function for the random variable $R_d$, defined as the number of steps it takes before it reaches distance $d$. For e.g., $P_{R_d}(R_d = r; d=10) = P_{x,y}(x_{(r)}^2 + y_{(r)}^2 \geq d^2 \text{ and } x_{(r-1)}^2 + y_{(r-1)}^2 < d^2 \text{ and } x_{(r-2)}^2 + y_{(r-2)}^2 < d^2 \cdots)$

where $x_{(r)},y_{(r)}$ are the coordinates at the $r$th step.

I tried simulating these with independent random samples and got expectations that go as $d^2 + \frac{d}{2}$, not $d^2$.

I am trying to estimate with certain precision $\tau$ and show that even when given the joint distribution on $x_{(i)},y_{(i)}$, we get $d^2$.

What would the best way be to estimate this expectation? Should I use MCMC methods, like Metropolis Hastings method? Would I set it up $R$ dependent on samples taken randomly from the distribution $p_{x,y}(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

When running the following R code

```
> time2<-function(d){
#average time to distance d
T=1e4
stopin=rep(0,T)
mov=rbind(c(-1,0),c(1,0),c(0,1),c(0,-1))
for (t in 1:T){
  start=rep(0,2)
  while (start%*%start<d){
    start=start+mov[sample(1:4,1)]
    stopin[t]=stopin[t]+1}}
return(mean(stopin))
}

> for (d in 30*(1:20)) 
+  times[d/30]=time2(d)

> lm(log(times)~log(30*(1:20))-1)

Call:
lm(formula = log(times) ~ log(30 * (1:20))-1)

Coefficients:
     log(30 * (1:20))  
                1.011
```

I get a near perfect fit for $d^2$ as the average time to distance $d$:
[image]

However, as pointed out by whuber, the fit in $d+d^2$ is better:

```
> lm(log(times)~log(30*(1:20)+sqrt(30*(1:20)))-1)

Call:
lm(formula = log(times) ~ log(30 * (1:20) + sqrt(30 * (1:20))) - 
    1)

Coefficients:
log(30 * (1:20) + sqrt(30 * (1:20))) 
                                   1
```

[image: enter escription here]

Comment: Thank you for the hint! This is very useful. It seems like you're running a timed simulation and getting a best log-linear fit. Is there no way to more accurately sample rather than run a simulation? For instance, say we want a precision of 12 digits. This would mean would have to run multitudes of simulations (computationally intractable, no?). Can we instead run a MCMC method to sample to get a more accurate estimate for the expectation on $R$? I'm new to the approximate inference methods.

Comment: I do not understand the above questions: (a) which population or distribution do you want to sample from? (b) MCMC being a simulation method, where is the gain in precision? (c) why would you require a 12 digit precision for the log-linear fit?

Comment: You data are an even *better* fit to the model $d^2 + d$.  (It obviously is not a "perfect" fit, nor should it be.) In fact, with larger values of $d^2$ the slope appears to get flatter and flatter.

Comment: @whuber: I agree that the fit looks better. But is there any theoretical explanation for $d^2+d$? Else I could also try $d^2+.78d$ or any other combination...

Comment: Asymptotically it must be $d^2 + o(d^2)$, to be sure.  The error terms are related to the geometry of lattice points within circles, which will be important only for the smallest distances.  You can see this in simulations of all possible values of $d^2$ less than around $50$.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. You're right in that in fact there is no need to run MCMC method and that $d^2 + o(d^2)$ is the best asymptotic estimation. @AS provided an elegant way of solving this for small $d$ using a linear system of equations defined on $T(x,y)$ , which represents the expected time it takes for an atom starting at $x,y$ to reach a distance $d$. The solution is in the comments section of my same post: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506808/computation-of-average-number-of-hops-for-an-atom-reach-a-certain-distance?noredirect=1#comment3069779_1506808).